# Android studio emulator white screen with search bar

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I've Installed the newest version of Android Studio,
and I tried to change the settings ANGLE(D3D11) and OpenGL but it still does not work.

In More>Settings>OpenGL ES Renderer and (in my case) i set it to Angle(D3D11) or Angle(D3D9) or Swiftshader. After that  i restarted the emulator but not working

And I tried this also:

1. Tools > AVD Manager
2. Select virtual device
3. Click on Edit (pencil icon for me)
4. Click "Show Advanced Settings"
5. Look for Emulated Performance - Graphics
6. Select "Software" option

but still not working

[image]

Comment: You put a screenshot of your AVD (Android Virtual Device - the emulator) settings. Did you actually launch the emulator?

Comment: Yes i did launch the emulator

Comment: You have to downgrade or upgrade android sdk. First try updating sdk(or android studio) for me 28 was working last year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have  updated the Android studio , SDK and emulator and it worked thanks
, HandLeg